# Xamarin iOS: Not opening .xib & .storyboard files Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I am adding new **Empty Storyboard**, **Empty User Interface** & **Storyboard View Controller** in Visual Studio(Connected to MAC machine through network). But these files are not opening at all. However I am able to open existing .storyboard file and newly added **View**(.xib).
Go through the screenshots and suggest me how to open it or it is not possible to open? Below selected UI templates are not opening

[image]

and below image showing Visual studio blank UI on designer and right side selected UI's files which showing blank UI after opening

[image]

See below **Empty User Interface** .xib view after dropping any control on it, it got shrink to that view only

[image]

Comment: You can try to add some View Controllers or Views in it.

Comment: Oh you are excellent. It solved **Empty Storyboard** & **Storyboard View Controller** problem. But when I am dropping controls on **Empty User Interface** (.xib) It is showing only single control and we can't use constraints also.  Please see my updated screenshot in question

Comment: If you just put a single view in it(UIImageView). Yes you can't add its constraints, because it's just a single View(lack of father view or controller). You can try to add a UIViewController, then in it you can add views with constraints.

Comment: Now my above issues have been solved :).

Comment: Yeah sure you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After we create a xib file, it presents a blank UI. so we can add some items in it. But if we just add a single view in it, it can't be added with some constraints. We should add a super view first:

[image]

Then constraints can be used on this `UIImageView`. More over if you want to use this customized view, using the code below to initialize it:

```
public static CustomViewName Create()
{

    var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("EmptyXib1", null, null);
    var v = Runtime.GetNSObject<MyTestViewController>(arr.ValueAt(0));

    return v;
}
```